# How to get file properties in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I want to get the file properties like "Description"、"ProductName"

How to get these properties in vb6?

I've tried use FileSystemObject, but it seems like can't get the "Description" properties.

Thanks for reply.
I use code below to get the file properties.
Hope this will help others who have the same problem with me.

```
Private Declare Function GetFileVersionInfo Lib "Version.dll" Alias "GetFileVersionInfoA" (ByVal lptstrFilename As String, ByVal dwhandle As Long, ByVal dwlen As Long, lpData As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFileVersionInfoSize Lib "Version.dll" Alias "GetFileVersionInfoSizeA" (ByVal lptstrFilename As String, lpdwHandle As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VerQueryValue Lib "Version.dll" Alias "VerQueryValueA" (pBlock As Any, ByVal lpSubBlock As String, lplpBuffer As Any, puLen As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As Any, ByVal Source As Long, ByVal length As Long)
Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

Public Function GetFileInformation(ByVal fileFullPath As String) As String
Dim lDummy As Long, lSize As Long, rc As Long
Dim lVerbufferLen As Long
Dim sBuffer() As Byte
Dim lBufferLen As Long
Dim bytebuffer(255) As Byte
Dim Lang_Charset_String As String
Dim HexNumber As Long
Dim buffer As String
Dim lVerPointer As Long

Dim ProdName As String

GetFileInformation = ""
buffer = String(255, 0)

lBufferLen = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileFullPath, lDummy)
If lBufferLen >= 1 Then

    ReDim sBuffer(lBufferLen)
    rc = GetFileVersionInfo(fileFullPath, 0&, lBufferLen, sBuffer(0))
    If rc <> 0 Then
        rc = VerQueryValue(sBuffer(0), "\VarFileInfo\Translation", lVerPointer, lBufferLen)
        If rc <> 0 Then
            MoveMemory bytebuffer(0), lVerPointer, lBufferLen
            HexNumber = bytebuffer(2) + bytebuffer(3) * &H100 + bytebuffer(0) * &H10000 + bytebuffer(1) * &H1000000
            Lang_Charset_String = Hex(HexNumber)

            Do While Len(Lang_Charset_String) < 8
                Lang_Charset_String = "0" & Lang_Charset_String
            Loop

            .sCompanyName = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "CompanyName", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sFileDescription = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "FileDescription", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sFileVersion = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "FileVersion", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sInternalName = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "InternalName", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sLegalCopyright = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "LegalCopyright", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sOriginalFileName = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "OriginalFileName", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sProductName = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "ProductName", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            .sProductVersion = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "ProductVersion", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
            GetFileInformation = GetStringValue("\StringFileInfo\" & Lang_Charset_String & "\" & "ProductName", lVerPointer, lBufferLen, sBuffer)
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function

Private Function GetStringValue(ByRef searchString As String, ByVal lVerPointer As Long, ByVal lBufferLen As Long, ByRef sBuffer() As Byte) As String
Dim buffer As String
Dim strTemp As String
Dim rc As Long

GetStringValue = ""
buffer = String(255, 0)
rc = VerQueryValue(sBuffer(0), searchString, lVerPointer, lBufferLen)

If rc <> 0 Then
    lstrcpy buffer, lVerPointer
    GetStringValue = Mid$(buffer, 1, InStr(buffer, Chr(0)) - 1)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: You probably would have to use Windows APIs. [This link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?446195-How-to-read-file-properties-Comments-title-keywords-etc) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: @aaa646123 please add your own answer summarizing what worked, if no one else has done so. That way your question may benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

This requires Windows 2000 or later.  I'm not sure the property system had been extended to this level of coverage in older OSs like Windows XP yet so you may need Windows Vista or later:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const ssfDESKTOP = 0
    Const COL2 = 20

    Show
    With CommonDialog1
        .DialogTitle = "Select a PE file"
        .CancelError = True
        .Flags = cdlOFNExplorer _
              Or cdlOFNFileMustExist _
              Or cdlOFNPathMustExist _
              Or cdlOFNLongNames _
              Or cdlOFNShareAware
        .InitDir = App.Path
        .Filter = "Programs (*.exe)|*.exe|Libraries (*.dll;*.ocx)|*.dll;*.ocx"
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowOpen
        If Err Then
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        With .NameSpace(ssfDESKTOP).ParseName(CommonDialog1.FileName)
            AutoRedraw = True
            Print "Name:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .Name
            Print "Product Name:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.Software.ProductName")
            Print "Size:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print Format$(.Size, "#,##0"); " bytes"
            Print "File Version:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.FileVersion")
            Print "Date Accessed:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.DateAccessed")
            Print "Date Created:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.DateCreated")
            Print "Date Modified:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.DateModified")
            Print "Company:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.Company")
            Print "Copyright:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.Copyright")
            Print "File Description:"; Tab(COL2);
            Print .ExtendedProperty("System.FileDescription")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

See `propkey.h` in a recent Windows SDK for the definitions of the available extended properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to propkey.h  I find another Windows properties name in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props